# click on a button automatically when page loaded and button appears

Tags: javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var inPage = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('CLICK AGAIN NOW') > 1,
    pr = document.querySelector("button.now-all.all-button");

if (inPage && pr) pr.click();
});
```

Page loaded! The button disappears automatically but I would like to get clicked "CLICK AGAIN NOW" button automatically when it appears on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (inPage && pr) {
pr.click();
}
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. For example, you're not including the closing bracket in your code snippet (from `$(document).ready(function() {`), which could lead to confusion. Please provide some [context surrounding your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), and see the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on how to write great answers :)